# Is the IQOS heat-not-burn cigarette safe?

Tags: smoking, lungs, second-hand-smoke, tobacco, e-cigarette-vape

I am researching the topic of electronic cigarettes and have recognized that Philip Morris has recently introduced in some markets the IQOS heat-not-burn cigarettes.

What is their safety profile in comparison to standard cigarettes and electronic cigarettes?